# exogenous in VARAMX

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, arima

I have a data frame with the columns date, total and C2 - C7 and I'm trying to run multivariate VARMAX with the target total so the endog is total and the exog are C2 - C7 but for some reason it keeps give me an error about the dimensions of the endog

this is the code:

```
# Convert the date column to a datetime type
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])

# Set 'date' as the index
data.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# Select relevant columns
data = data[['total', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7']]

endog_variable = 'total'
exog_variables = ['C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7']

train_size = 330

train_endog_data = data[endog_variable].iloc[:train_size]
train_exog_data = data[exog_variables].iloc[:train_size]
test_data = data.iloc[train_size:]

# Fit a VARMAX model
order = (1, 0)  # Order of the VARMAX model (p, q)
model = VARMAX(endog=train_endog_data, exog=train_exog_data, order=order)
results = model.fit(disp=False)
```

and this is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[64], line 32
     30 # Fit a VARMAX model
     31 order = (0, 3)  # Order of the VARMAX model (p, q)
---> 32 model = VARMAX(endog=train_endog_data, exog=train_exog_data, order=order)
     33 results = model.fit(disp=False)
     35 # Forecast total installs using the VARMAX model

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/varmax.py:189, in VARMAX.__init__(self, endog, exog, order, trend, error_cov_type, measurement_error, enforce_stationarity, enforce_invertibility, trend_offset, **kwargs)
    186 self._k_order = _min_k_ar + self.k_ma
    188 # Number of states
--> 189 k_endog = endog.shape[1]
    190 k_posdef = k_endog
    191 k_states = k_endog * self._k_order

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

VARMAX is for multivariate endog variables. You are passing only a single column as endog, which is what is causing the error. To use VARMAX, endog should be a DataFrame with 2 or more columns.

If you want to have a univariate endog, you can use SARIMAX and still include the exog variables.